# KeyError: in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to run groupby with multiple columns and aggregate column and aggregate Operator.

I will get all of above as parameter to method. I have to do groupby:

```
result = df.groupby([groupByColumns])[aggColumn].agg(aggOperation)
```

Here

```
groupByColumns: clientId,state,branchId
aggColumn: amount
aggOperator: sum
```

But I am getting this error

```
KeyError: ''
```

I am not good in Panda. How can I correct my statement above?

Answer (score 0):

If `groupByColumns` is already a list, remove `[]` in `groupby`:

```
groupByColumns = ['clientId', 'state', 'branchId']
aggColumn = 'amount'
aggOperation = sum

out = df.groupby(groupByColumns)[aggColumn].agg(aggOperation)

# OR

out = df.groupby(['clientId', 'state', 'branchId'])['amount'].sum()
print(out)

# Output
clientId  state  branchId
A         M      X           3
          N      Y           3
B         M      X           9
          N      Y           6
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'clientId': list('AAABBB'),
                   'state': list('MMNMMN'),
                   'branchId': list('XXYXXY'),
                   'amount': range(1, 7)})
print(df)

# Output
  clientId state branchId  amount
0        A     M        X       1
1        A     M        X       2
2        A     N        Y       3
3        B     M        X       4
4        B     M        X       5
5        B     N        Y       6
```

Answer (score 0):

The groupby column requires a 1D list in input parameter. In your case, your groupByColumns is ['clientId', 'state', 'branchId'], and while using the groupby function, you are using the list operator, essentially making it a 2d list of length 1. This is what is happening in your case
df.groupby([['clientId', 'state', 'branchId']])['amount'].sum()

**Solution**
As answered by @Corralien, use the same command but without the list operator, this way in the groupby command you'll be passing a 1d list and it should work !